# javascript button doesn't work with bottle.py

Tags: javascript, python, bottle

Learning to use [Bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org) and made a page with a button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>button</title></head>
    <body>
        <script>function test(){ 
        console.log("a");
        document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "abcd"; 
        return false;}</script>
        <form onsubmit="return test()">
            <button type="submit">Button</button>
        </form>
        <div id="b"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I press the button, <del>nothing prints out on the javascript console</del> the div element does not get populated with text.

```
from bottle import route, template, run

@route('/button')
def b():
    return template('button')
```

This is (obviously) a minified version of what is actually happening in my app.

Comment: Something else is the problem then. Your HTML and JS are valid: http://jsfiddle.net/3Cq94/

Comment: I updated my example.  It works on jsFiddle, but not in Bottle.

Comment: Bottle is a serverside framework and doesn't interact with the clientside code. Check the generated HTML. Your current HTML works as well: http://jsfiddle.net/3Cq94/3/

Comment: it works now.  looks like I misnamed the onsubmit function here at home.  I was calling Test() instead of test().

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript and html code are perfectly valid as @Blender said, have you checked if you have a valid code, by viewing the actual source that is delivered by the http response?